# i'm trying a twitch viewer bot for testing on my own channel and my code is not working

Tags: python, python-2.x, twitch

guys this is the error code i don't know what to do

```
 File "threads_viewer.py", line 56
print(f"URL : {url[:30]}...\n")
                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

there is the python code

```
def get_url(self):
    url = ""
    try:
        streams = session.streams(self.channel_url)
        try:
            url = streams['audio_only'].url
            print(f"URL : {url[:30]}...\n")
        except:
            url = streams['worst'].url
            print(f"URL : {url[:30]}...\n")
```

please help :(

Comment: The actual error is often above the place pointed to by the error message. I can't see a problem in the shown code.

Comment: You have two *try* and one *except*. This leads to the Python interpreter getting confused about where the actual error is. If you use Python 3.10.5 it will tell you about the mismatched try/except